# Weird return javascript regex without flag 'g'

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

code = `DAK~ 800 SUB~10/21/2015 CAK~10/21/2015`

i just want to get `800`

wheh i use this regex:

code_fix = `match(/([0-9]){3}/g)`
It returns = `[ '800', '201', '201' ]`

but when i try use the regex without flag `g` why is what my result looks like:

```
[ '800',
  '0',
  index: 21,
  input: 'DAK~ 800 SUB~10/21/2015 CAK~10/21/2015' ]
```

Comment: you just use [0], because it is first match in your expression, others are extra info you can ignore if you don't need.

Comment: try this `code_fix=match([0-9]{3})`

Comment: @YOU sorry, but I want to make the code look clean so I don't like to use [0]

Comment: @jamesjelo4kul I got this from it
`'800',
  index: 21,
  input: 'DAK~ 800 SUB~10/21/2015 CAK~10/21/2015'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a word-boundary. Try this:

```
/\b([0-9]){3}\b/g
```

See this [reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) for more on word boundaries.

Comment: actually I don't want to use flag g, but your code help me solve to the problem, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If use `([0-9]){3}`, it also two matched,`800` is all match,
and `0` is group match by `([0-9])`, it match the last `0` in `800`